# It says AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sample'

Tags: python, random-forest, sample

I am trying to split my data and create a hold-out set. The error that shows is on the `holdout` line and I am not sure why.

splitting into training, test and holdout sets

```
train_set, test_set = train_test_split((new_df,(.8 * len(new_df))))

holdout = train_set.sample(frac=0.2, random_state=10)

train_set = train_set.drop(holdout.index)
```

Comment: Well, `train_set` is a list, not an instance of whatever class has a `sample` method like you expected. What is `train_test_split`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: how are we supposed to know what these variables are?

Comment: A good old `print(train_set)` statement would tell you what's going wrong quite quickly...

Answer (score 0):

The Error has to be in your train_test_split method, which Returns a list, and not an object of yours, which could have the .Sample method. Your problem could propably be solved by just setting train_set[0].Sample, granted your method Returns a list with just one element.